# Python: Loop through a dataframe and create one plot for each datapoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

The below code generates a line plot. Here x axis is common and y axis is split into two (y1 and y2), which are plotted against x. I'm using *savefig()* to save the plot as a .PNG file.

Right now, I need images to be generated at each data points (or for each value of x), so that these images would be like frames of the original graph. I tried using '*Iterrows*' to loop through the data frame. However, this was not solved.

PS: I inted to use these generated frames to convert into video using *ffmpeg*. *Animate()* doesn't serve my purpose here, hence not using it. Quick help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
def MakeLineGraph(stats,title, savegraph) :

x = stats[stats.columns[1]]
y1 = stats[stats.columns[2]]
y2 = stats[stats.columns[3]]
xlab = list(stats)[1]
ylab = list(stats)[0]

fig = plt.figure()
pli = plt.subplot()

pli.plot(x, y1, color='g', linewidth=5.0, label='label1')
pli.plot(x, y2, color='y', linewidth=5.0, label='label2')

plt.xlabel(xlab)
plt.ylabel(ylab)
plt.title(title)

# Removing the plot frame lines.
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)

ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()

leg = plt.legend()

for line in leg.get_lines():
    line.set_linewidth(6)

if len(x) < 25:
    pli.xticks(x.tolist())

plt.show()

if (savegraph == True):
    fig.set_size_inches((19.2, 10.8))
    fig.savefig(image_folder + 'Progress.png', transparent=True, dpi=600)
```

Comment: I'd suggest re-writing that to a function that takes *one* datapoint and makes *one* plot, and using df.apply(..., axis=1) (even if that is slow). You can then gather up the frames and make your animation.

Comment: `matplotlib.animation` was written for exactly such purpose. You would need to create the figure and axes only once and then only change the data within a function that `FuncAnimation` calls repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys.
I solved the issue slightly modifying the code. To be noted that I'm just sharing the core part only, Formatting remains the same as above.

```
def MakeLineGraph(stats,title, savegraph) :

x = stats[stats.columns[1]]
y1 = stats[stats.columns[2]]
y2 = stats[stats.columns[3]]
xlab = list(stats)[1]
ylab = list(stats)[0]

fig, pli = plt.subplots()

pli = plt.subplot()
pli.imshow(pltimg, extent=[0, 95, 0, 55])

line, = pli.plot(x, y1, color='g', linewidth=5.0, label='label1')
for n in range(len(x)):
    line.set_data(x[:n], y1[:n])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.savefig('./frames/Frame%03d.png' % n)

line, = pli.plot(x, y2, color='y', linewidth=5.0, label='label2')
for n in range(len(x)):
    line.set_data(x[:n], y2[:n])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.savefig('./frames/Frame%03d.png' % n)
```